# Looking to protect ranges google sheets one they have been approved

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

First post!

Im a newbie to coding and need some help on google apps script.

I am looking to protect rows from editing once they have been approved (The range for approved aleard had protection so only authorised persons can approve). Once it becomes approved i want a script to run to protect that row from being edited.

Link to file I am using:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-LJfJ_qtq6_fC7zIrxi9Qs9vocuSCurlfMYMzwoe1iM/edit?usp=sharing

My code so far (but getting stuck):

```
function protectRows (){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Protect once approved");
  var col = 3
  var approvedColumn = sheet.getRange("D2:D").getValues()
 
 
   // what code needs to go here?


  var range = sheet.getRange(row, col);
  var protection = range.protect().setDescription('LOCKED NOW ' + row);

var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
 protection.addEditor(me);
 protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
 if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
   protection.setDomainEdit(false);
 }
}
```

Many Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to protect the columns "A" to "D" when the checkbox of the column "D" is checked.

In this case, how about the following modified script?

#### Modified script:

```js
function protectRows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Protect once approved");
  var approvedColumn = sheet.getRange("D2:D").getValues();
  var protectedRows = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE).map(p => p.getRange().getRow());
  approvedColumn.forEach(([d], i) => {
    var row = i + 2;
    if (d === true && !protectedRows.includes(row)) {
      var range = sheet.getRange(`A${row}:D${row}`);
      var protection = range.protect().setDescription('LOCKED NOW ' + row);
      var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
      protection.addEditor(me);
      protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
      if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
        protection.setDomainEdit(false);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

#### Note:

- For example, when you want to execute the script when the cells are edited, please install OnEdit trigger to the function of `protectRows` as the installable trigger. By this, when the cells are edited, the checkbox of column "D" is checked and the rows are protected.

#### References:

- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)